# Specify starting image slide of image slider by page URL query string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider

Is there a way to start a jQuery slider on a certain image based on URL query-string?  My home page has a list and when clicking on a certain item it redirects to the new page with jQuery slider.

I want to starting image to be linked to the item clicked on the home page.

Example of HTML:

```
<div id="div">
    <ul id="list">
        <li class="slide">
            <a href="/Profile/1">First</a>
        </li>
        <li class="slide">
            <a href="/Profile/2">Second</a>
        </li>
        <li class="slide">
            <a href="/Profile/3">Third</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

JQuery Slider code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var currentSlide = 1;
        var $profile = $('.PhysicianProfile');
        var $slider = $profile.find('.PhysicianSlider');
        var $details = $slider.find('.PhysicianProfileDetails');

        // Slide Left
        $('.profileBtnLeft').on('click', function () {
            $slider.animate({ 'margin-left': '+=1026px' }, 800, function () {
                currentSlide--;
                if (currentSlide === 1) {
                    $('.profileBtnLeft').prop("disabled", true);
                }
            });
        });

        // Slide Right
        $('.profileBtnRight').on('click', function () {
            $slider.animate({ 'margin-left': '-=1026px' }, 800, function () {
                currentSlide++;
                if (currentSlide == $details.length) {
                    $('.profileBtnRight').prop("disabled", true);
                }
            });
        });

    });
```

Right now, if I click any list item on the Home page it takes me to the "Profile" page but slider always starts on first image.

If I click, Second list item, is there a way for the Profile page to open with slider starting with second Image?

Thanks!

Comment: Can we see your jQuery slider code? Odds are that you'll just have to change the code on the destination page to have it look at the URL on page load and modify the slider's initial properties accordingly.

Comment: I added to the jQuery slider code to the original post.  I'm not using any plugins.  I thought it would be easier to create the slider to make adjustments to it later.

Comment: To be clear, are you using the [jQuery UI slider](http://jqueryui.com/slider/#default)?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear.  I have created an Image slider on the profile page.  If the Second link is clicked, I would like the Second image to display on the profile page.  From there, I would like to be able to click the left and right button to view the other Images on the slider.